# Add converter to page resources from code behind

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I would like to add a specific instance of a class to the resources of a page then use that class as a converter, so in my page constructor I put:

```
this.Resources.Add("converterASD", new ASDConverter());
```

then bind to it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converterASD}}"/>
```

but I keep getting this exception:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an
>   exception.

I'm a bit new to WPF, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use more information from the exception.

Two suggestions:

1. Make sure that you add the resource before the call to InitializeComponent().
2. Try switching it to a dynamic resource.

Comment: I haven't tried adding it before InitialiseComponent(), will try, need to read up more about dynamic resources. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the Converter you would like to use in the resource section of the page like the following example. (I recommend you declare the converter in XAML instead of the code-behind)

**Example:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ConverterExample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300"
        d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="VisibilityController" IsThreeState="False" />
        <ListBox
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=VisibilityController, Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Height="100" Width="100" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: "I recommend you declare the converter in XAML instead of the code-behind." Why?

Comment: "Separation of concerns" & Maintainability :)

Comment: I usually declare converters in App.xaml as a 'global' resource, in this case code behind is required